# C array content that out of bounds is '\0' but not random value

Tags: c, string

I have one array

```
char * string = “hello”；
```

When I read `string[5]`, the value is 0. Shouldn't this be a random value?

My doubt comes from when I use `memcmp` to compare two arrays.  The argv length is longer than the array length, but it works correctly. I know that `memcmp` stops when it reads a '\0', but the array has no '\0'. I tested this on Dev C++.

Comment: `strcmp` stops when it reaches '\0'; `memcmp` does not.

Answer (score 5):

No, the array `"hello"` contains six `char`s, the last being `'\0'`. So in your situation `string[5]` is guaranteed to be `'\0'`. `string[6]` however, gives you undefined behaviour.

But `memcmp` doesn't stop at a 0-byte, only `strcmp` does.

Comment: thx，it's my mistake，so can memcmp compare array which has no '\0'?

Comment: `memcmp` compares two memory regions with arbitrary content. It doesn't care whether any bytes in those regions are 0.

Comment: @user1534282: yes, `memcmp()` can compare such an array as long as you pass correct size to it. Note that you will usually want to check that both arrays have the same size first.

Answer (score 4):

The `"hello"` is a string constant which is guaranteed to be null-terminated. Which means that the it contains an additional `'\0'` character after the last character specified by you.

In other words, it's practically equivalent to:

```
char string[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

You can easily check that using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char string[] = "hello";

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(string));
    return 0;
}
```

(note that you should not be using `%d` with `sizeof()` in a production code)

That program will output `6`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes memcmp can compare an array which has no '\0'.
For instance look at this code.

```
int main () {

     char str1[]= "hello";
     char str2[]= "hello";
     std::cout << memcmp(str1, str2, 5);
     std::cout << memcmp(str1, str2, 6);
     return 0;
}
```

Both of them print 0 on the screen. When the size is 5, it is compared without '\0'. when size is 6, '\0' is also compared.
memcmp simply compares the block of memory.